# How to update Android Studio binding generated class

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.1

After update of Android Studio to 3.1.1 I have the following problem: when I add any item to my `layout.xml` in my `java` file Android Studio does not recognize it.

[image]

Only solution I found is close and open Android Studio. Do you know any appropriate solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

did you tried build -> rebuild project ? that should refresh all the generated code.